# Dark souls: What shield or shield types stop npc overhead mashes?

Tags: dark-souls

So there is a capra demon, and when it first engages enemies it always does a dual weapon jump overhead smash attack that pancakes the player. I always used parry shields so I don't know if this still happens with a tower shield. Are there shields in dark souls that stop that specific capra demon attack?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is definitely possible to block this attack. It's all a question of Stamina. The way that blocking these and most attacks works is that the particular attack's Stamina damage is subtracted from your current Stamina. If your Stamina reaches zero, you end up staggered, and if your Stamina goes too far negative, you fail to block the attack at all. This is the issue with the Capra Demon's overhand smash: It does a ton of Stamina damage.

Thankfully, there is a way to mitigate this. Before an attack's Stamina damage is applied, it is first reduced by your shield's Stability. The current guess is that this is a direct percentage: I.e. if an attack does 200 Stamina damage and your shield has 60 Stability, you instead take (100% - 60%) * 200 = 80 Stamina damage. Small shields top out at ~45 Stability, standard shields top out at ~60, and greatshields hit 80+ Stability. This is why heavier shields tend to block better, even when they have the same DR%.

Long story short, if you want to be able to block the Capra Demon's overhead smash, you'll need a shield with high Stability—like the [Balder Shield](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/balder-shield), [Tower Kite Shield](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/tower-kite-shield), or [Caduceus Kite Shield](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/caduceus-kite-shield), which are all available pre-Capra—and a decent amount of Stamina (from Endurance). If you have a Greatshield handy, use that instead, and upgrading shields usually increases their Stability. In the end, though, it might just be more convenient and Stamina-efficient to dodge the attack, if you can.

Comment: great answer. That's really cool. I just thought that the overhead smash bypasses shields in general, but anyway thanks for this helpful info.

Comment: You can also increase your stability by wielding the shield two-handed.

Comment: so here is something funny. 
I took your advice, started with the knight class for that knight kite shield. It's got 58 starting stability. I upgraded to +3 to 61 stability. I also have like 16 endurance and I laughed my ass off when the kapra demon's jump attack pancaked me. It wasn't really hard to kill him because he only does that attack one time.

Comment: Capra's overhead smash really does a freakish amount of Stamina damage. I wasn't kidding about that. I was able to block it in my sword-and-board run through, but my Endurance was fairly overleveled, and I got lucky with a pimpin' [Black Knight Shield](http://darksouls.wikidot.com/black-knight-shield) drop. I wasn't able to block the attack with the Knight's starting shield at the time, but I understand it's possible without _too_ much power-leveling. Really, you're supposed to block those kinds of attacks with a proper Greatshield, but Dark Souls does account for overachievers.

Comment: @JoshuaLittle ...but... "Prepare to Die"? It says it on the box? No? Ok then...